# Getting a value from a JSON string in purely MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm looking for a **single query** that's **purely MySQL**. The goal of this query is to utilize things such as `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, `CONCAT`, or whatever it needs to, in order to find a value in a string.

Let's say that the string looks something like this:
`{"name":34,"otherName":55,"moreNames":12,"target":26,"hello":56,"hi":26,"asd":552,"p":3722,"bestName":11,"cc":6,"dd":10,}`

My goal is to get the value of `target`, in this case, `26`. However, `"target":26` might not always be in that location in the string. Neither would any of the other properties. On top of that, the value might not always be `26`. I need some way to check what number comes after `"target":` but before the `,` after `"target":`. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Is JSON_EXTRACT a purely MySQL solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one ?

```
create table sandbox (id integer, jsoncolumn varchar(255));
insert into sandbox values (1,'{"name":34,"otherName":55,"moreNames":12,"target":26,"hello":56,"hi":26,"asd":552,"p":3722,"bestName":11,"cc":6,"dd":10}');

mysql root@localhost:sandbox> SELECT jsoncolumn->'$.target' from sandbox;
+--------------------------+
|   jsoncolumn->'$.target' |
|--------------------------|
|                       26 |
+--------------------------+
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this function to get value from JSON string in MYSQL

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CAP_FIRST_CHAR;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION getValueFromJsonSring(jsonStr VARCHAR(250), getKey VARCHAR(250))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(250) deterministic

BEGIN

  DECLARE output VARCHAR(250);  -- Holds the final value.
  DECLARE data VARCHAR(250);    -- Holds the exctracted value from JSON
  SET getKey=CONCAT('"',getKey,'"');
  SET data= TRIM(LEADING ':' FROM 
                substring_index(
                    substring_index(
                        substring_index(
                            substring_index(
                               SUBSTRING(jsonStr, 2, LENGTH(jsonStr)-2)
                                , getKey , '2'), 
                            getKey, 
                            -1
                          )
                        , ',', '1'), 
                    ',', 
                    -1
                )

            );
  SET output =SUBSTRING(data, 2, LENGTH(data)-2);

  RETURN output;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT getValueFromJsonSring('{"amount":"400.34","departmentId":"7","date":"2017-06-02","PONumber":"0000064873","vendor":"44"}',"departmentId");
```